# Workflow Not working

Tags: visualforce, workflow

I am using a workflow on Account object  with following criteria :

```
(Account: Shipping Street equals null) or 
(Account: Shipping City equals null) or 
(Account: Billing Zip/Postal Code equals null) or 
(Account: Shipping State/Province equals null)
```

The Workflow Action includes:

```
SUBSTITUTE(ShippingStreet,null, BillingStreet)
```

It is not replacing the null values of `ShippingStreet` when left empty on creation with the billing address.
In debug log , Although it shows field updated. Thanks

Comment: I believe the answer is that Strings without values are not null, but instead are empty strings.  Try `SUBSTITUTE(ShippingStreet '',BillingStreet)`.  `ISBLANK` should be used to test for empty string values if you are using formulas in your triggering conditions

Comment: I have already used the substitute using SUBSTITUTE(ShippingStreet,'',"ckshbk") , not working still

Comment: IS there any way to check null text for substitute , Already checked all way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct action should be:

```
BLANKVALUE(ShippingStreet, BillingStreet)
```

From the documentation on [functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_functions.htm):

> Determines if an expression has a value and returns a substitute expression if it does not. If the expression has a value, returns the value of the expression.

Comment: Thanks for the reply , However , Is there any specific reason why substitute is not working and is there any particular way to check it for null value

Comment: @cloudlover That's just not what `SUBSTITUTE` was designed to do. `BLANKVALUE` seems like it does *exactly* what you are looking for...